# WEKA: Print the Indexes of Test data instances w.r.t original data at the time of cross validation

Tags: weka, cross-validation, test-data

I have a query about the indexes of test data instances chosen by weka at the time of cross validation. How to print the indexes of the test data instances which are being evaluated ?

==================================

I have chosen:

Dataset            :  iris.arff

Total instances    : 150

Classifier          : J48

cross validation:   10 fold

I have also made output prediction as "PlainText"

=============

In the output window I can see like this :-

inst#     actual                  predicted           error      prediction

1        3:Iris-virginica       3:Iris-virginica             0.976

2        3:Iris-virginica       3:Iris-virginica              0.976

3        3:Iris-virginica       3:Iris-virginica              0.976

4        3:Iris-virginica       3:Iris-virginica              0.976

5        3:Iris-virginica       3:Iris-virginica              0.976

6        1:Iris-setosa         1:Iris-setosa                      1

7        1:Iris-setosa         1:Iris-setosa                      1

....
...
...

Total 10 test data set.(15 instances in each).

======================

As WEKA uses startified cross validation, instances in the test data sets are randomly choosen.

So, How to print the indexes of test data w.r.t the data in original file?

i.e

inst#     actual                  predicted           error      prediction

1        3:Iris-virginica       3:Iris-virginica             0.976

This result is for which instance in main data (among total 50   Iris-virginica) ?

===============

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search, I have found that the  below youtube video is helpful for the above problem.

Hope this will be helpful for any future visitor with same queries.

[Weka Tutorial 34: Generating Stratified Folds (Data Preprocessing)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tyHpHOn7R8Y)